# Consistent (10054, WSAERROR) while uploading dataframe to Google BigQuery

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble running this code. It executed fine a couple weeks ago for a set of ~160 dataframes, but recently, Google BigQuery has begun to throw WSAERROR's while trying to run the code.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
import pandas_gbq as pd_gbq
import time
import tqdm
from google.cloud import bigquery, exceptions

for file in glob.glob(stage_folder)[:34]:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    pd_gbq.to_gbq(df, output_table, project_id = project_id, progress_bar= True, if_exists='append', chunksize = 330000)
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(300)
```

I've tried to modulate the chunksize, but this has only delayed the onset of the WSAERROR, not prevented it. My research has shown this could be an issue with the headers, but how do you change the headers in to_gbq?

Here's the most recent Traceback. I can provide the full one if needed, Stack is just interpreting the full traceback as spam.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SysCallError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\OneDrive - The Home Depot\Documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in _send_until_done(self, data)
    316             try:
--> 317                 return self.connection.send(data)
    318             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantWriteError:

~\OneDrive - The Home Depot\Documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in send(self, buf, flags)
   1736         result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
-> 1737         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1738         return result

~\OneDrive - The Home Depot\Documents\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1638                     if errno != 0:
-> 1639                         raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
   1640                 raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")

SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems to be a Windows problem. Not in Python, not in BigQuery, but in Windows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981344/an-application-may-receive-the-10054-error-when-the-application-receiv

Comment: Thanks Felipe! I followed the guideline there and managed to run my script for a longer period than before, however, still ended up with the same result. I forgot to mention that I am under a VPN policy. I'll test this off VPN and report my findings